# How to stock a list in a Django Model?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to stock a list in a Django Model like this :

```
class Search(models.Model):
    result = models.CharField(max_length=100,
                              null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    eotp = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    reference = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    contains = []
```

But I don't think that it's the best way to stock a list, because I have an error when i want to create an element (like this):

```
new_search = Search(result=result, name=name, eotp=eotp, reference=reference, date=date, contains=contains)
```

"Search() got an unexpected keyword argument 'contains'"

Do you know if there is a better way to stock lists in django models or if I have to do this in another way ?

Thanks

Comment: Create a new model with a `ForeignKey` to your `Search`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem a ManyToMany Field with all that i want to stock in my list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use django's `ArrayField` so that you can stock your list into your model.

Use this code for your model:

```
class Search(models.Model):
    result = models.CharField(max_length=100,
                              null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    eotp = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    reference = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    contains = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), blank=True) #---> Set as per your requirements
```

Documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield